# Reading and writing in python

Tags: python

I'm pretty new at coding and I'm trying to figure out how to solve this question:
Find all the headers that start with # and lines that have the word "PASS" in the 7th column and print them to new.vcf. Pass may show up in other columns but when in the 7th column it will appear alone and in all caps. These files are tab delimited.
I've already completed the first part of the question but can't figure out how to pull "PASS" from the 7th column. Here's the total code I have so far.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
myfile= open("temp.vcf","r")
outfile= open("new.vcf","w")            
for data in myfile: 
    data = data.strip("\t")
    if data[0] == "#":
        outfile.write(data +"\n")
myfile.close()
outfile.close()

myfile=open("temp.vcf","r") 
outfile=open("new.vcf","a")

data=myfile.readline()
while data == "PASS":
    outfile.write(data+"/t")
    data=myfile.readline()  

myfile.close()
outfile.close()
```

Comment: A sample input and an expected output would be really helpful in order to give you some real help for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing your line,

```
while data == "PASS":
```

to

```
while data.find("PASS") >= 0 :
```

which uses the find() method on a string ?

Answer (score 0):

Split your line by the delimiter and check index 6 for "PASS"

```
line = "#   a   b   c   d   e   PASS    f"

columns = line.split("   ")

print columns[6]
```

Comment: Why the down vote?  Probably should have used /t but sounds like homework, a nudge in the right direction is better than doing it.

Comment: Wow, I really appreciate all of your input. It's working great now. Also, thanks for the advice about the     str.split().

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need to open and close your files twice. You should perform both operations at the same time. Second, to read data in a specific column, you need to break each line into those columns. `str.split` is your friend.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
myfile= open("temp.vcf","r")
outfile= open("new.vcf","w")            
for data in myfile:
    if data[0] == "#":
        outfile.write(data + "\n")
        continue
    columns = data.split("\t")
    if columns[6] == "PASS":
        outfile.write(data + "\n")
myfile.close()
outfile.close()
```